# Assigning an identifier to a polygon using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, identifier, polygons

I want to be able to allow an end-user to draw polygons onto a map using OpenLayers.  This is easily done.  However, I need to be able to associate a user defined identifier, or in other words a region name, to the polygon(s).  For the life of me I can't figure out how to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Two options are available:

**1. with `attributes`:**

Here is an example from OpenLayers: [OpenLayers.org's example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-features-with-text.html)

```
var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(pointList);
var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
  new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]));
polygonFeature.attributes = {
  name: "dude",
  age: 21,
  favColor: 'purple',
  align: 'lb'
};
```

**2. With Styles:**

Here is the example from HazardMapping.com: [Example from Hazardmapping.com](http://hazardmapping.com/openlayers_styles.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Vector's styles here, in [OpenLayers](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style)
With that, you can name a good label for Your polygons